# Docusign dotnet 4.7 examples

Tags: asp.net, docusignapi

I am trying to find dotnet 4.7 Docusign examples to add to my Umbraco website but I can only find dotnet Core.
Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 0):

If you are using either Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code, DocuSign has free extensions that would add code examples that also support .NET Framework in addition to .NET Core.
You can use these to either directly add them to your existing project, or creating a new DocuSign project.
Here are the links:
VS - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DocuSign.DocuSignVSExtension
VS Code - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DocuSign.docusign-vscode-extension